# How to handle javascript side with php function that returns a CSV file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, csv

I have this `php` function which returns me a `CSV` file. This function needs the parameter `$getid` which I send through the url:

```
$getid = $_GET['id'];
$funcid = $_GET['funcid'];

if ($funcid == 'get_download') {

function get_download($dbmi, $getid) {

    $stmt = $dbmi->prepare("CALL spStartDownload(?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $getid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    if ($fp && $result) {
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');

        fputcsv($fp, $headers, ";");
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          fputcsv($fp, $row, ";");
        }
    }

    $stmt->close(); 

    echo $fp;   
}
}
```

To send this parameter, I use this `$.ajax()` function:

```
function startDownload(id) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        showLoader('start...'); 
        var funcid = "get_download";    
        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'functions/getdata.php',
            data: {
                funcid: funcid,
                id: id
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(myData) {
             if (myData == null) {
                showAlert();
             } else {


             }

             hideLoader();

        })          
        .fail(function() {showAlert();}); //When getJSON request fails      
    }, 0);
}
```

I'm a bit stuck here because the CSV file wont start downloading but when I type the url in the browser with the two parameters (funcid and id) it does work..

Any thoughts?

Comment: do you ever run the function or just declare it?

Comment: In my getdata.php I have this: `if ($get_function == 'get_download') {
 if ($user_data['mi_active'] == 1) {
  $getid = $_GET['id'];
  echo get_download($dbmi, $getid);
 }
}` The part above the function in my question was just for simplification. Also: the `echo` part in the `php` function is a `return` in real life..

Comment: but your js.. does it ever run? your php won't execute a js function (unless done on ajax success return)

Comment: Instead of using Ajax, you should open the url in a new tab. By default, the browser will download the CSV and close the tab when it's done.

Comment: Tnx Adrien, that worked!